# Ruby generate static page from erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I created an application that has only one page. And there is a code like Ruby and HTML. There's a code of nokogiri who sends a request to the site and take out the data.
The problem is that I do not need to get up at every request of this page and send a request to another site. I need to do it so that she once in 1 hour made a request and generated static when somebody open my web app.

Is it possible to do this somehow without using databases? Just generate a static HTML page from my erb.

And set the automatic execution of the initial script once in a while.

Comment: If you don't want to fetch the data every time, then you must "cache it" (= persist it), therefore you will need a database. Also, you will need a "cache expiration" (refresh of the DB records) every X hours, which can simply be a scheduled task (see whenever gem) triggering a rake task.

Comment: I founded https://github.com/javan/whenever for tasks run

Comment: It's possible without databases and most likely without Rails. **(1)** Write a ruby script that generates a HTML file. **(2)** Use a web server (Apache, nginx, whatever is available) to serve that static file. **(3)** Set up cron to run the ruby script every hour.

Comment: If you want a super simple solution, you could even just run this off github pages and have a script that pushes updates to the repo once an hour.